# How do I make a div appear on an image

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, show, hidden

So, for school I have to make this game. And for that I have to make text appear when I click on an image. 
I tried it on a button, but that doesn't look good, so I want to make a hidden div on an image visible on click. 
For some reason I just can't seem to make it work.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html-->
```

```
<head>
    <title>crime scene</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="crimescene.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="img1">
        <img src="images/nummer2.png" alt="nummer2" data-hint="2" />
    </div>

    <div id="hint-1" class="hidden">Hint 1</div>

    <div id="img2">
        <img src="images/nummer3.png" alt="nummer3" data-hint="3" />
    </div>

    <div id="img3">
        <img src="images/nummer4.png" alt="nummer4" data-hint="4"/>
    </div>

    <div id="img4">
        <img src="images/nummer1.png" alt="nummer1" data-hint="1"/>
    </div>

    <div id="hint" class="hidden">this is a hint</div>
    <button id="button">Show element</button>

    <script src="crimescene.js"></script> 

</body>
```

JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';

    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var hint = document.getElementById("hint");

var showHint = function (event) {
    console.log(this);
     if data-hint === '1'
     hint.classList.toggle('hidden');
    };

var img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    console.log(img);

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("click", showHint);
    };

function show(hint) {
    };

button.addEventListener('click', show);

};
```

How do I make the tekst show when I click on an image? Does anyone know?? (I cannot use jQuery)

Comment: What does the 'if data-hint === '1'' do?

Comment: I'm not sure, my teacher did that... But I think it makes the hint hidden.